# Removing punctuation and creating a dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, punctuation

I'm trying to create a function that removes punctuation and lowercases every letter in a string. Then, it should return all this in the form of a dictionary that counts the word frequency in the string.

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
def word_dic(string):
    string = string.lower()
    new_string = string.split(' ')
    result = {}

    for key in new_string:
        if key in result:
            result[key] += 1
        else:
            result[key] = 1

    for c in result:
        "".join([ c if not c.isalpha() else "" for c in result])

    return result
```

But this what i'm getting after executing it:

```
{'am': 3,
 'god!': 1,
 'god.': 1,
 'i': 2,
 'i?': 1,
 'thanks': 1,
 'to': 1,
 'who': 2}
```

I just need to remove he punctuation at the end of the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"".join([ c if not c.isalpha() else "" for c in result])` creates a new string without the punctuation, but it doesn't *do* anything with it; it's thrown away immediately, because you never store the result.

Really, the best way to do this is to normalize your keys *before* counting them in `result`. For example, you might do:

```
for key in new_string:
    # Keep only the alphabetic parts of each key, and replace key for future use
    key = "".join([c for c in key if c.isalpha()])
    if key in result:
        result[key] += 1
    else:
        result[key] = 1
```

Now `result` never has keys with punctuation (and the counts for `"god."` and `"god!"` are summed under the key `"god"` alone), and there is no need for another pass to strip the punctuation after the fact.

Alternatively, if you only care about leading and trailing punctuation on each word (so `"it's"` should be preserved as is, not converted to `"its"`), you can simplify a lot further. Simply `import string`, then change:

```
    key = "".join([c for c in key if c.isalpha()])
```

to:

```
    key = key.rstrip(string.punctuation)
```

This matches what you specifically asked for in your question (remove punctuation at the end of words, but not at the beginning or embedded within the word).

Comment: Upvoted for including options. Defaultdict int would create more compact code right?

Comment: @AntonvBR: Yes. And `collections.Counter` would be more explanatory (with equivalent behavior). That said, even without `defaultdict(int)` (or imports of any kind), you could do `result[key] = result.get(key, 0) + 1` and avoid the LBYL four-liner in favor of a one-liner.

Comment: Hi!! i really apreciated all of your help :) the code provided by ShadowRanger really delivered what i wanted. I feel annoyed because i saw i was near to get it, i just forgot to store the "".join part in a variable. I'll pay more attention the next time. 
Thanks a lot guys!!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use that famous Python's [batteries included](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batteries_Included).

```
>>> sentence = 'Is this a test? It could be!'
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(re.sub('\W', ' ', sentence.lower()).split())
Counter({'a': 1, 'be': 1, 'this': 1, 'is': 1, 'it': 1, 'test': 1, 'could': 1})
```

Leverages [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for counting words, and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for replacing everything that's not a word character.

Comment: Nice (+1) but for readability I'd use more lines and variables.

Comment: Converting non-word characters to spaces, then splitting, is going to make `"it's"` get treated as the words `"it"` and `"s"`. Usually, you want to split on whitespace, then strip punctuation, or strip punctuation and split on whitespace, not convert punctuation to whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.punctuation` to recognize punctuation and use `collections.Counter` to count occurence once the string is correctly decomposed.

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

line = "It's a test and it's a good ol' one."

Counter(word.strip(punctuation) for word in line.casefold().split())
# Counter({"it's": 2, 'a': 2, 'test': 1, 'and': 1, 'good': 1, 'ol': 1, 'one': 1})
```

Using `str.strip` instead of `str.replace` allows to preserve words such as *It's*.

The method `str.casefold` is simply a more general case of `str.lower`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you want to reuse the words later, you can store them in a sub-dictionary along with its ocurrences number. Each word will have its place in a dictionary. We can create our own function to remove punctuation, pretty simple.
See if the code bellow serves your needs:

```
def remove_punctuation(word):
    for c in word:
        if not c.isalpha():
            word = word.replace(c, '')
    return word


def word_dic(s):
    words = s.lower().split(' ')
    result = {}

    for word in words:
        word = remove_punctuation(word)

        if not result.get(word, None):
            result[word] = {
                'word': word,
                'ocurrences': 1,
            }
            continue
        result[word]['ocurrences'] += 1  

    return result


phrase = 'Who am I and who are you? Are we gods? Gods are we? We are what we are!'
print(word_dic(phrase))
```

and you'll have an output like this:

`{
    'who': {
        'word': 'who', 
        'ocurrences': 2}, 
    'am': {
        'word': 'am', 
        'ocurrences': 1}, 
    'i': {
        'word': 'i', 
        'ocurrences': 1}, 
    'and': {
        'word': 'and', 
        'ocurrences': 1}, 
    'are': {
        'word': 'are', 
        'ocurrences': 5}, 
    'you': {
        'word': 'you', 
        'ocurrences': 1}, 
    'we': {
        'word': 'we', 
        'ocurrences': 4}, 
    'gods': {
        'word': 'gods', 
        'ocurrences': 2}, 
    'what': {
        'word': 'what', 
        'ocurrences': 1}
}`

Then you can easily access each word and its ocurrences simply doing:

```
word_dict(phrase)['are']['word']       # output: are
word_dict(phrase)['are']['ocurrences'] # output: 5
```

Comment: wow that's some master code!! thanks a lot, this helped and teached me a lot!! :)

Comment: @Miguel2488, no problem.